# selecting specific columns and * in same mysql query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have two queries:

`Array allIds = select id from table1 order by time`

and

`select * from table1 where id in (allIds[0],allIds[1],...,allIds[9])`

Is there any way to combine these queries into one?  I need all the data from both queries.

Comment: Have you tried `JOIN`?

Comment: LIMIT 11 if you mean 11 first results from the first query?

Comment: ok to clarify.  The first query will return 100 ids.  The second query will return * from the first 10 of the ids. * is 10 other columns.

Comment: So my answer should work. LIMIT 10

Comment: but i want all 100 ids from the first query.  and I want all 10 columns from the first 10 ids returned in the first query.

Comment: What's the problem with having * in the first query then? You are grabbing some extra data you can ignore...

Comment: @sashkello, running these two queries is faster than running 'select * ...' in the first query.  I want to join them into one query.

Comment: I'm quite sure it souldn't be much faster. There should be virtually no difference between selecting all or one column. The way you are doing it now unlikely can be improved, as you can not select different number of columns for different id's.

Comment: @sashkello. I want it to be in one transaction, so there is only one connection to mysql.

Comment: What's the problem with getting all columns for all ids??? Test it and you'll see there is no speed issues here.

Comment: I have tested that and it is slower. but forget about performance or anything else.  I just want to know if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for if I understand this right.

Basically, the following query will select ALL rows from the second table where they have the same ID's as the 10 most recent rows from the first.

Doe this make sense? Or have I missed the mark?

```
SELECT table.id, table2.*
FROM table
INNER LEFT JOIN table AS `table2` ON table.id IN (
    SELECT table.id
    FROM table
    ORDER BY table.time
    LIMIT 0,10
)
```

Comment: well theres only 1 table.  But i don't think this returns the ids from 10->100

Comment: It should be returning everything in the database for the 10 most recent IDs. Are you looking for something other than this?

Comment: I need all the data returned by the two queries.  So the first query returns all 100 ids.  the second query returns all columns for the first 10 ids

Comment: It's getting late for me and not having an sqlfiddle to tinker with makes visualizing the result of this hard, but I *think* this is more along the lines of what you were looking for? Ideally, the data of the table should be being selected along with the IDs you're looking for in a left join which should preserve the rows from `table` that won't have matching records in the data. It may also need some tinkering, like I said no data set to play with makes it difficult especially since you're trying to get two (partially) distinct data sets in one query.

Answer (score 0):

There's two way to do it:

The first way is more or less a simple combination of your two queries:

```
select * from table1
where id in (
    select id
    from table2)
order by time
```

The second, and better, way is a join:

```
select table1.id
from table1
join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
order by time
```

Comment: there's only one table.  I don't think either query returns what I need.  Your first example won't return all 100 ids, and the second example won't return * from the first 10 ids.

Comment: I don't understand why you need the subquery then. What is you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to get 100 ids.  Then I'm trying to get all columns from the first 30 of those 100 ids.

Comment: How is that different from simply getting all columns from the first 30 ids?

Comment: because then I'm missing 70 ids.

Comment: But you said you wanted the first 30 of the first 100. That's the same thing as just getting the first 30. Can you explain what the significance of "30" is in your requirements.

Comment: lol. i need 100 ids then i need all columns from the first 30 of those 100 ids.  So what I need to be returned is:
 1. all columns from ids 0->29. 2. ids from 30->100

Comment: One of the basic rules of SQL is that for any table (and a result set is a table), all rows have the same number of columns. Your request is therefore impossible. You can either have 100 rows with all columns as one query (you can ignore the columns for 31-100), OR you need two queries - one query for 1-30 with all columns, and another query for 31-100 with just the id column. A compromise solution would be to return nulls for all non-id columns for 31-100.  There are no other options. So, what of those options is it you want?